# Printing ToC entry with \large makes it go into the margin

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I want to print the `section` names in the ToC in a larger font than everything else.

Here is the command for it:

```
\titlecontents{section}
    [1.5em]
    {}
    {\large\sffamily\bfseries\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1.5em}}
    {\hspace{-1.5em}}
    {\hspace*{\fill}\sffamily\bfseries\large\contentspage}
```

However, because of the `\large` command the number of the section turns out to be in the margin:

[image]

How can I fix it? Here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{titletoc}


\titlecontents{section}
    [1.5em]
    {}
    {\large\sffamily\bfseries\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1.5em}}
    {\hspace{-1.5em}}
    {\hspace*{\fill}\sffamily\bfseries\large\contentspage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{One}
\subsubsection{}
\subsubsection{title}
\subsubsection{title}


\section{Two}
\subsubsection{}
\subsubsection{title}
\subsubsection{title}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Increase the `[1.5em]` to something like `[2em]`, or else decrease the `{1.5em}` to something like `{1.1em}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I want `perfect` alignement. This is not going to work, because different digits have different width.

Comment: with tex, unless you are explicitly specifying something else, you will only get lining/tabular figures, which are always the same width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by `em` unit depending on font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\setbox0\hbox{\large\sffamily\bfseries\xdef\myoneandhalfem{\the\dimexpr1.5em}}

\titlecontents{section}
    [\myoneandhalfem]
    {}
    {\large\sffamily\bfseries\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1.5em}}
    {\hspace{-1.5em}}
    {\hspace*{\fill}\sffamily\bfseries\large\contentspage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{One}
\subsubsection{}
\subsubsection{title}
\subsubsection{title}

\section{Two}
\subsubsection{}
\subsubsection{title}
\subsubsection{title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know `titletoc` and what `{\hspace{-1.5em}}` stands for, but perhaps you may need there too the `\hspace{-\myoneandhalfem}`, although the picture seems fine even without it.

It is better not to use `em` at all when alignments are at stake, and font changes may occur. Unfortunately even the hard-coded distances in LaTeX table of contents code use it (but as much is hard-coded anyhow, that was not so much of a problem).